# How can I add additional cutom fields on airflow tasks and see them in ariflow UI tasks detail?

Tags: python, airflow

I need to add additional data to aiflow tasks that can be seen in the detail section of the task in the Airflow UI. There is a way to do it?

Can I add these data from variables that are declared in the task function (at runtime)?

thank you

I searched on the airflow UI, try to ask chatgpt and bard, and did some google search. didn't find anything